# vim visual mode help

Tags: vim

In normal mode to open the Find-Replace window with the word under cursor

```
map <leader>f :promptrepl <c-r><c-a><cr>
```

Now, I want something similar but with the visual selection instead of the word under the cursor, like

```
vmap <leader>f <y><Esc>:promptrepl <c-r>0<cr>
```

but this gives me the error `E73: tag stack empty`

*Any advise appreciated*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing it correctly, except that you have an extra pair of `< >` in your map.

```
vnoremap <leader>f y<Esc>:promptrepl <c-r>0<cr>
```

I'm not sure if there is another way to retrieve the visually selected text. Of course, you could append a register to your yank, one that's rarely used for you (say `"ny`), so you don't mess with your register `0`. Then change the `<c-r>0` to `<c-r>n`.

Comment: Hmm, strange, I have no errors here (MacOS X). Try it "interactively". I mean, do the exact strokes yourself, because I don't see where this comes to be related to the tag stack.

Comment: that's what I don't understand, I can't do the mappings, but `:promptr <c-r>0<cr>` per se works fine

Comment: just in case: are you using `vnoremap`? maybe your map is then remapped to something else.

Comment: yes that's what I needed `vnoremap` instead of `vmap`, Thanks

Comment: This is a rule :-) As @ZyX says (btw, tired of saying) _"don't use *map unless you know why you prefer it to nore version"_

Comment: fixed with `ddZZ` that's so right, I won't even remember that I have this mapping